# can scroll content but without appearing the scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my content still can scrolling, but the scroller not appear. 
I write my css like this :

```
#content-three{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.block_s{
    width:90%;
    height:30%;
    margin:2.5%;
    padding:2.5%;
/*  border:5px solid gray; */
}
.isi{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    font-size:100%;
    float:right;
}
```

and html file like this:

```
<div id="content-three">
    <div class="block_s">
       <ul class="scroll_img" id="sc01">
         <li><img src="images/port/picture1.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="images/port/picture2.jpg" /></li>
         <li><img src="images/port/picture3.jpg" /></li>
            <span class="button prevButton"></span>
            <span class="button nextButton"></span>
       </ul>
           <div class="isi">
             <h2>Judul</h2>
                <p>lalalalala llllllllllllaaaaaaaaaaalll </p>
           </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

(content with block_s class not just one there is alot)
what should I do ? what I need to add ? css ? or jquery ?
thank you for suggest and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width of inner container bigger than parent one, that's how you will hide scroll bar at hidden area.